# Role Based Authorization using JWT - Spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Hope you all are doing great! I am implementing JWT Role Based Authorization in spring boot.

I have been able to implement it. The tutorial that I am following is this

https://github.com/only2dhir/spring-security-jwt

The user is being sucessfully registered. And then I assign that user a role like ADMIN.

Now I have this api  `@GetMapping("/users")`

that should be accessed by ADMIN. However when I access this api, it gives me this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of 
"io.jsonwebtoken.Claims.get(Object)" is null
```

This errors comes from these methods:

JwtTokenUtil:

```
 public static final String AUTHORITIES_KEY = "scopes";
 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(final String token, final Authentication 
  exsitingAuth, final UserDetails userDetails){

    final JwtParser jwtParser = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret);

    final Jws<Claims> claimsJws = jwtParser.parseClaimsJws(token);

    final Claims claims = claimsJws.getBody();

    final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities=
    java.util.Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(","))
         .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", authorities);
}
```

This line gives error

```
 java.util.Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(","))
```

Creating authentication:

```
 UserDetailsWithToken UserDetailsWithToken = new UserDetailsWithToken();
    authenticate(authenticationRequest.getEmpID(), 
 authenticationRequest.getPswd());

    final UserDetails userDetails = 
 userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getEmpID());

    
    final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authenticationRequest.getEmpID(),
                authenticationRequest.getPswd()
            )
    );
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    
    final String token = 
   jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails,authentication);
```

Comment: Try printing `claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY)` to your log or console.  What does it look like?

Comment: What do you mean by printing to your log? I am testing my apis using postman. I do not have a front end for my application yet. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: can you provide the code of the token creation?

Comment: @gaetanTEMATE please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing to add the authorities.

See the code here .... I eidted my answer to create a token ...

```
public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails, Authentication 
   authentication) {
    List<String> roles = user.getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return doGenerateToken(userDetails.getUsername(), roles);
}
```

ANother method

```
public String doGenerateToken(String username, List<String> roles) {
        try {
            Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
            claims.put("username", roles);
            claims.put(AUTHORITIES_KEY, username);
            return Jwts.builder()
                    .setClaims(claims)
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 120000))
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
                    .compact();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Add the authorities string and pass it to doGenerateToken method.

Thanks,

Atul

Comment: I did as you mentioned . it gives me this error ``A granted authority textual representation is required`` can you plz help? @Atul

Comment: I modified my answer, you need to change the Map<String, Object> to Map<String, String> .... This will work I guess.

Comment: Changing it into ``Map<String, String>`` gives me alot of other errors. previously it was working but just gives me this error ``A granted authority textual representation is required ``  @Atul

Comment: Edited my answer ... Need to change few things like constants but logically it will help you to create a token

Comment: I just added  ``claim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authorities)`` my token is being created perfectly the only error i am getting now is ``A granted authority textual representation is required ``

Comment: Have you tried the code which I posted? Still you have the issue?

Comment: your code is not working. It gives me errors on ApplicationConstants and logger @Atul

Comment: As I mentioned, you have to changes those constants to your requirement. Try it, I changed few things. Remove the logger statement.

Comment: What should I write in my catch exception if not logger? @Atul

Comment: e.printStackTrace();

Comment: does not work. By using ``e.printStackTrace()``  , ``InvalidKeyException `` gives error

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are not setting your authorities in the jwt token try setting it:

```
    return doGenerateToken(authorities, userDetails.getUsername());
...

private String doGenerateToken(String authorities, String subject) {
        return
            Jwts.builder()
                .claim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authorities)
                .setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 120000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
    }
```

make sure to create your authentication correctly

```
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "myPassword");

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject().authenticate(authenticationToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication.getPrincipal(), authentication);
```

Comment: I did as you mentioned and it gives this error ``A granted authority textual representation is required`` Please help @gaetanTEMATE

Comment: it depends on how you are creating your Authentication 
   authentication, make sure it look like something like this, (updated answer)

Comment: please see my updated question. Can you tell me if i am creating authentication correctly. Or what do I need to change? @gaetanTEMATE